# Automatic Generation of a JavaHelp Index File

Tags: indexing, javahelp

I just started working with the JavaHelp package. I have done some basic modifying of the Table of Contents and such with no problems.

My issue arises in that I have created various new help files (added to an existing project within my dev team) and added various sections to existing help files. I now need to make sure that the index.xml file is updated, useful, and meaningful.

It seems as though this should be generated automatically but I can't seem to find a way to do it, and any solutions I've tried to use don't seem to work.

Is there even a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a [CodeSmith template](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) to update this index file.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski